# File size in UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: utf-8

I have created a file with UTF-8 encoding, but I don't understand the rules for the size it takes up on disk. Here is my complete research:

1. First I created the file with a single Hindi letter 'क' and the file size on Windows 7 was
   8 bytes.
2. Now with two letter 'कक' and the file size was 11 bytes.
3. Now with three letter 'ककक'and the file size was 14 bytes.

Can someone please explain me why it is showing such sizes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first three bytes are used for the [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) `EF BB BF`.

Then, the bytes `E0 A4 95` encode the letter क.

Then the bytes `0D 0A` encode a carriage return.

Total: 8 bytes. For each letter क you add, you need three more bytes.

Comment: BOM is completely redundant in UTF-8 files (byte order is completely and unambiguously specified, unlike for UTF-16LE vs UTF-16BE), but it appears that some Windows tools insist on putting one there anyway.  Maybe switch to a different tool, or a better platform.

Comment: @tripleee: The Unicode consortium states that "use of a BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8" ([p. 36](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch02.pdf)), but it can be useful, for example for editors that need to handle different encodings. Since UTF-8 is backwards-compatible to ASCII, it may happen that a UTF-8 file doesn't contain any characters above `0x7f`, so editors that scan the first 64 KB of a file to guess its encoding (for example that's what EditPad does), could be fooled.

Comment: I wouldn't say COMPLETELY redundant.. it does unambiguously indicate that the file is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: If the file doesn't contain any characters above 0x7f, does it matter?  But fair enough, it could have some uses.

Comment: @tripleee: Assume you're starting out with a UTF-8 file without "special characters", then edit that, introducing special characters, then saving that, now with an incorrect encoding. Or if the special characters occur only after the position up to which the "encoding sniffer" is active.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks its performing exactly the way you explained. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

On linux based systems, you can use `hexdump` to get the `hexadecimal` dump(used by Tim in his answer) and understand how many bytes a character is allocating.

`echo -n a | hexdump -C`
`echo -n क | hexdump -C`

Here's the output of the above two command.
[image]